# Call base member after virtual dispatching (emulate virtual destructor-like dispatching)

Tags: c++

Virtual dispatching simply selects the "right" thing to call in a hierarchy.

I want to implement a functionality similar to the behaviour of destructors, where the derived destructor is called first and then all destructors along the hierarchy up to the upmost base.

The client should just define the member function and call order should be resolved automatically. I have a draft solution that uses CRTP and no virtual calls; it has its advantages and disadvantages :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
struct Dispatcher
{
    void f() {
        ((T*)this)->f();
        std::cout << "calling f base\n"; 
    }
};
    
struct Implementation : Dispatcher<Implementation>
{
    void f() {
        std::cout << "calling f derived\n"; 
    }
};
    
int main()
{
    shared_ptr<Dispatcher<Implementation>> obj = make_shared<Implementation>(); 
    obj->f(); 
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/924b0e0e7203c941)</kbd>

This way the user simply derives from dispatcher and defines the method she's interested in (this implies that the dispatcher defines all the interface needed)

On the downside all drawbacks of CRTP are introduced and I don't really have virtual dispatching. Is there a more concise and idiomatic way to achieve this ? Can it be done for hierarchies of greater depth ?

### EDIT

I have a reset method and I want a call to `Derived::reset` to trigger a call to `Base1::reset` up to `BaseN::reset` without the user actually writing the call to these functions, just as a call to the destructor would trigger calling destructors up the hierarchy.

Comment: What about calling `Dispatcher<Implementation>::f();` in `Implementation::f`? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6fc7f81b756838ad

Comment: @DenisBlank The whole point is to free the client from manually making such calls. If I were to impose additional constraints on "how to write your member functions" then virtual dispatch would suffice. Again, I'm looking for a way to emulate the behavior of virtual destructors; you wouldn't manually call the base destructor there now, would you?

Comment: Are you actually considering using this abomination? What is wrong with real virtual dispatch?

Comment: @BЈовић Real virtual dispatch does not call the base method after calling the relevant one. What's not clear about that? Say I have a reset method and I want a call to `Derived::reset` to trigger a call to `Base1::reset` up to `BaseN::reset` without the user actually writing the call to these functions (just as a call to the destructor would trigger calling destructors up the hierarchy). Is this concept clear to you?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, base classes are not supposed to "know" about its derived classes farther than the virtual table, then if derived classes want to call functions up in the hierarchy tree is up to them. The only work around I know is CRTP and I don't see a way of going farther than one hierarchy level on that. But you could make a separate wrapper virtual function that calls the current reset and then calls itself one level up, you can put the definition in some macro so the clients of this class just have to add the macro. Not exactly what you are looking for but does the trick.

Comment: It seems to me too complicated. What real problem do you try to solve? Do you really need be so smart? Let me paraphrase Bjarne Stroustrup. He said something like: "Make Simple Tasks Simple". If you create super smart solution, nobody else will understand it, not even you after some period, because understanding of someone's code is much harder then creating new code. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nesCaocNjtQ If I take and show any of source codes provided in answers below  to average C++ programmer and ask: "What is this code good for?", they will hardly come with satisfactory answer.

Comment: @qub1n Ideally a supersmart solution would be simple and intuitive. Full disclosure, I expected answers with simpler code than the one I provided but the opposite happened. A question's "goodness" is not measured by its practicality (that's where my mentality on inquiring things differs from SO) but that's just my opinion. I value the techniques presented by Barry (`for_each_base` is sth worth learning) and the "behavioral" programming style showcased by  Piotr has a lot of character. Alternatively one can "TLDR"  the whole thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [`std::tr2::direct_bases`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/libstdc++/api/a01610_source.html), this is actually remarkably straightforward. Hopefully this makes it into some C++ standard in the future, but for now the following example actually compiles on gcc.

First, let's alias our type trait. The following gives us a `std::tr2::__reflection_typelist` with all of the direct bases of `T`:

```
template <typename T>
using direct_bases_t = typename std::tr2::direct_bases<T>::type;
```

So for this hierarchy:

```
struct A { };
struct B : A { };
struct C : B { };
```

For `A`, it will give an empty list and for `C` will give a list containing just `B`. (If you don't want to use `direct_bases`, you will have to explicitly provide the base classes, see end of answer). All we have to do then is just iterate:

```
template <typename T, typename F, typename... Bases>
void for_each_base(T* t, F f, std::tr2::__reflection_typelist<Bases...> )
{
    using expander = int[];
    expander{0,
        (void(
            for_each_base(static_cast<Bases*>(t), f)
        ), 0)...
    };
}

template <typename T, typename F>
void for_each_base(T* t, F f)
{
    f(t);
    for_each_base(t, f, direct_bases_t<T>{});
}
```

That will call `f` on the object, and then walk up the hierarchy until complete. So with a particularly simple functor:

```
struct Logger {
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T* ) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    C c;
    for_each_base(&c, Logger{});
}
```

The output is:

```
void Logger::operator()(T*) [with T = C]
void Logger::operator()(T*) [with T = B]
void Logger::operator()(T*) [with T = A]
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd01fec0fb906a51)

For your case, you'd basically just want:

```
for_each_base(obj, [](auto p){ p->reset(); });
```

---

Without `direct_bases`, we would simply have to provide our own typelist and our own manual list of bases for each class. Something like:

```
template <typename... > struct typelist { };

struct A { using bases = typelist<>; };
struct B : A { using bases = typelist<A>; };
struct C : B { using bases = typelist<B>; };

template <typename T>
using direct_bases_t = typename T::bases;
```

Otherwise the structure of the solution is the same (though now using `typelist` instead of `std::tr2::__reflection_typelist`).

Answer (score 2):

You want to imitate destructors-like behavior for some function.

The smartest way to imitate destructors behavior is by using destructors.

I mean to call these functions in destructors of some parallel hierarchy to your classes.

First you need to know the base classes - I've tried to use __direct_bases - new extensions of gcc - but if failed ([gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67735)), so let use C++ solution:

```
template <typename T>
using GetBaseType = typename T::Base;
using NoBase = void;
```

The above requires that every class in this hierarchy must have `Base` typedef - that can be solved in future releases of C++.

So having base classes - we can create two hierarchies - one for non-const, one for const functions:

```
template <typename T>
class CallUp;

template <>
class CallUp<NoBase>
{
public:
   template <typename Op, typename T>
   CallUp(Op&& ignoreOperation, T&& ignoreObject) {}
};


template <typename T>
class CallUp : public CallUp<GetBaseType<T>>
{
public:
    template <typename Op>
    CallUp(Op&& op, T& obj) : CallUp<GetBaseType<T>>(op, obj), op(std::forward<Op>(op)), obj(obj)
    {}
    ~CallUp()
    {
        op(obj);
    }
private:
    std::function<void(T&)> op;
    T& obj;
};

template <typename T>
class ConstCallUp;

template <>
class ConstCallUp<NoBase>
{
public:
   template <typename Op, typename T>
   ConstCallUp(Op&& ignoreOperation, T&& ignoreObject) {}
};

template <typename T>
class ConstCallUp : public ConstCallUp<GetBaseType<T>>
{
public:
    template <typename Op>
    ConstCallUp(Op&& op, const T& obj) : ConstCallUp<GetBaseType<T>>(op, obj), op(std::forward<Op>(op)), obj(obj)
    {}
    ~ConstCallUp()
    {
        op(obj);
    }
private:
    std::function<void(T&)> op;
    const T& obj;
};

template <typename Op, typename T>
auto callUp(Op&& op, T& obj)
{
    return CallUp<T>(std::forward<Op>(op), obj);
}
template <typename Op, typename T>
auto callUp(Op&& op, const T& obj)
{
    return ConstCallUp<T>(std::forward<Op>(op), obj);
}
```

In destructors of this `callUp` hierarchy - you would get the behavior you want.

How to invoke these destructors - just define temporary of that type - it will be destructed immediately.

See example of usage:

```
class Foo0
{
public:
    using Base = NoBase;
    void reset()
    {
        std::cout << "reset Foo0\n";
    }
    void print() const
    {
        std::cout << "Foo0\n";
    }
};

class Foo1 : public Foo0
{
public:
    using Base = Foo0;
    void reset()
    {
        std::cout << "reset Foo1\n";
    }
    void print() const
    {
        std::cout << "Foo1\n";
    }
};

class Foo2 : public Foo1
{
public:
    using Base = Foo1;
    void reset()
    {
        std::cout << "reset Foo2\n";
    }
    void print() const
    {
        std::cout << "Foo2\n";
    }
};


int main() {
    Foo2 foo2;
    callUp([](auto&& obj){obj.reset();}, foo2);
    callUp([](auto&& obj){obj.print();}, foo2);
}
```

Output:

```
reset Foo2
reset Foo1
reset Foo0
Foo2
Foo1
Foo0
```

[ideone link](http://ideone.com/8ZaT03).

---

This framework can be extended.
E.g. the multi base classes can be done in this way:

```
template <typename ...T>
struct MultiBases {};

template <typename ...T>
class CallUp<MultiBases<T...>> : public CallUp<T>...
{
public:
    template <typename Derived, typename Op>
    CallUp(Op&& op, Derived& obj) : CallUp<T>(op, obj)...
    {}
};
template <typename ...T>
class ConstCallUp<MultiBases<T...>> : public ConstCallUp<T>...
{
public:
    template <typename Derived, typename Op>
    ConstCallUp(Op&& op, Derived& obj) : ConstCallUp<T>(op, obj)...
    {}
};
```

And example of usage:

```
class Foo01
{
public:
    using Base = NoBase;
    void reset();
    void print() const;
};

class Foo02
{
public:
    using Base = NoBase;
    void reset();
    void print() const;
};


class Foo1 : public Foo01, public Foo02
{
public:
    using Base = MultiBases<Foo01, Foo02>;
    void reset();
    void print() const;
};

class Foo2 : public Foo1
{
public:
    using Base = Foo1;
    void reset();
    void print() const;
};


int main() {
    Foo2 foo2;
    callUp([](auto&& obj){obj.reset();}, foo2);
    callUp([](auto&& obj){obj.print();}, foo2);
}
```

Output:

```
reset Foo2
reset Foo1
reset Foo02
reset Foo01
Foo2
Foo1
Foo02
Foo01
```

[Ideone link](http://ideone.com/MWjpd5)

---

The problem with calling virtual functions in non virtual way can be resolved on lambda level.

With this `object_class_t` class template we can get the "raw" class type of an object:

```
template <typename T>
using object_class_t = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;
```

So, assuming we have any of the reset function virtual - and want to call them in non-virtual way (what is desired behavior):

```
int main() {
    Foo2 foo2;
    auto nonVirtualReset = [](auto&& obj)
    {
         using ObjClass = object_class_t<decltype(obj)>;
         obj.ObjClass::reset();
    };
    callUp(nonVirtualReset, foo2);
    callUp([](auto&& obj){obj.print();}, foo2);
}
```

Comment: @stgatilov - I simplified my solution. .

Comment: Yes, now it is much better indeed!
User has only to make `Base` typedef in each class (perhaps it could be avoided if something like `std::bases` became standard). Doing a method call is not very beautiful, but it is quite easy to wrap into macro if wanted. Also, it is possible to do many different things (not just a single method call) in the lambda. BTW: does it work with multiple inheritance? with virtual inheritance?

Comment: Also, it seems that it is not possible to directly call a virtual function in this way (at least I do not know how to make non-virtual call of virtual method in lambda). It can be circumvented by moving method implementation into non-virtual method.

Comment: @stgatilov It requires a little more work - but it is possible to call virtual functions in non virtual way - just instead of `obj.foo()` - one must call `obj.ClassName::foo()`  - but to create such design is not as easy as to call with simple lambda. To get many bases classes - it is also doable - but will complicate a thing. I'll try to return to this answer (today?) and I'll provide an update. To get behavior for virtual base - that would be a hard goal - but also doable. Please let me know which of these are the most "must-have" for you? I can start from that one.

Comment: `ConstCallUp<T>` is completely unnecessary, you could just use `CallUp<const T>`. Also, given that you're requiring your classes to define their own bases, you don't need to write all the logic in destructors (which is unnecessarily complicated) - you could write it directly.

Comment: @Barry Well - if OP will decide some day to also take into account this "strange" rules about when destructor of `virtual` base should be called - then much easier is to achieve that by creating parallel hierarchy of classes and use this hierarchy destructors to make sure the rules are forced by compiler - not by programmer who might make mistake. Regarding `<const T>` specialization - good hint - thanks, but before I changed it - I must check it, if it works for all cases...

Comment: @PiotrNycz: Mostly I worry about ordinary virtual calls, i.e. when we call a virtual method by having a pointer of base class type, and we want the proper method to be called (with all its parents of course). If I'm not mistaken, simply calling `obj.reset()` would result in multiple calls of the same method (defined by runtime type of object). The trick with `decltype` that you have now fixes parent calls, but this solution is non-polymorphic: the methods being called are dependent on static type, not on the runtime type.

Comment: I do not think multiple inheritance is really important here. But in any case I wish that your answer includes information about multiple inheritance case for completeness. At least write whether it works as is, could probably work with some modifications, or is not doable at all.

Comment: I already provided multiple inheritance to this solution - and it was very smooth addition - just another specialization of `CallIUp` - nothing more - see update to my answer. I hope you do not need virtual inheritance which is not supported and would require a lot of changes and would complicate this solution.

Comment: @stgatilov I missed your last comment about `virtual` call. So you want to call all e.g. `reset()` in hierarchy even if this is called not from bottommost class pointer/reference?  Well - that can be achieved either by somehow deducing the real type of the object - or by adding virtual function to each of your classes. The latter is of course doable - the first - I am not so sure...

Answer (score 1):

This is an approach that that does not intrude into the bodies of the classes
in your hiererchy, but requires you to specify their base classes according to
a special rule in which the base class is always an instance of:

```
template<class Parent, class Child = void> struct chain;
```

A preliminary sketch: If you would ordinarily express the hierarchy like:

```
struct base 
{ ... virtual void reset(); ... };
struct child : base 
{ ... virtual void reset(); ... };
struct grandchild : child 
{ ... virtual void reset(); ... };
struct great_grandchild : grandchild 
{ ... virtual void reset(); ... };
struct great_great_grandchild : great_grandchild 
{ ... virtual void reset(); ... };
```

then instead you will express it like:

```
struct base 
{ ... virtual void reset(); ... };
struct child : chain<base> 
{ ... virtual void reset(); ... };
struct grandchild : chain<base,child> 
{ ... virtual void reset(); ... };
struct great_grandchild : chain<child,grandchild> 
{ ... virtual void reset(); ... };
struct great_great_grandchild : chain<grandchild,great_grandchild> 
{ ... virtual void reset(); ... };
```

As the sketch discloses, the solution gives a genuinely polymorphic hierarchy,
which can be of any depth.

Ordinary member functions of the classes may be invoked in the ordinary way, but
a "chained" member function - with destructor-like recursion - must be
invoked on some object of type `chain<P>` or `chain<P,C>`, where `C` is the
hierarchical child of `P`.

A base class such as `chain<grandchild,child>` of `great_grandchild`,
functions as a link in the hierarchy that encapsulates the upwardly recursive invocation
of `reset`. It takes both `grandchild` and `child` as virtual base classes 
- making them also virtual base classes of `great_grandchild`.
Thus on behalf of `great_grandchild` it can invoke both `this->grandchild::reset()` 
and `this->child::reset()`, and then recursively request the like on behalf of `child`. 
Recursion is terminated in the specialization `chain<T>`: hence:

```
struct child : chain<base> { ... };
```

Here is the definition of `chain`

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail {

    template<class ...> using void_t = void;

    template<class, class = void >
    struct has_base_type : std::false_type {};

    template<class T >
    struct has_base_type<T,void_t<typename T::base_type>> : std::true_type
    {
        using type = typename T::base_type;
    };

    template<class T>
    using has_base_type_t = typename has_base_type<T>::type;

    template<class T>
    struct has_real_base
    {
        static constexpr bool value = has_base_type<T>::value && 
            !std::is_same<has_base_type_t<T>,T>::value;
    };

    template<class Parent, class Child = void>
    struct chain : virtual Parent, virtual Child
    {
        using base_type = Parent;
        using child_type = Child;

        template<class T>
        static std::enable_if_t<has_real_base<T>::value>
        recurse(chain * const pd) {
            pd->base_type::base_type::reset();
        }

        template<class T>
        static std::enable_if_t<!has_real_base<T>::value> 
        recurse(chain * const pd) {}

        void reset() override {
            this->child_type::reset();
            this->base_type::reset();
            recurse<base_type>(this);
        }
        virtual ~chain() = default;
    };

    template<class T>
    struct chain<T> : virtual T
    {
        using base_type = T;
        void reset() override {
            this->base_type::reset();
        }
        virtual ~chain() = default;
    };

} // namespace detail

template<class Parent, class Child = void>
struct chain : detail::chain<Parent,Child>
{
    using base_type = detail::chain<Parent,Child>;
    void reset() override {
        this->base_type::reset();
    }
    virtual ~chain() = default;
};
```

You can append the following to make an illustrative program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct base
{
    virtual void reset() {
        std::cout << "calling base::reset()\n"; 
    }
    virtual ~base() = default;
};

struct child : virtual chain<base>
{
    void reset() override {
        std::cout << "calling child::reset()\n"; 
    }
    virtual ~child() = default;
};

struct grandchild : chain<base,child>
{
    void reset() override {
        std::cout << "calling grandchild::reset()\n";
    }
    virtual ~grandchild() = default;
};

struct great_grandchild : chain<child,grandchild>
{
    void reset() override {
        std::cout << "calling great_grandchild::reset()\n";
    }
    virtual ~great_grandchild() = default;
};

struct great_great_grandchild : chain<grandchild,great_grandchild>
{
    void reset() override {
        std::cout << "calling great_great_grandchild::reset()\n";
    }
    virtual ~great_great_grandchild() = default;
};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "obj1\n";
    shared_ptr<base> obj1 = make_shared<chain<base,child>>(); 
    obj1->reset();
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "obj2\n";
    shared_ptr<base> obj2 = make_shared<chain<child,grandchild>>();
    obj2->reset();
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "obj3\n";
    shared_ptr<base> obj3 = make_shared<chain<grandchild,great_grandchild>>();
    obj3->reset();
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "obj4\n";
    shared_ptr<base> obj4 = 
        make_shared<chain<great_grandchild,great_great_grandchild>>();
    obj4->reset();
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "obj5\n";    
    shared_ptr<grandchild> obj5 = make_shared<chain<grandchild,great_grandchild>>();
    obj5->reset();
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "obj6\n";    
    shared_ptr<base> obj6 = make_shared<chain<grandchild>>();
    obj6->reset();   
}
```

which should outpout:

```
obj1
calling child::reset()
calling base::reset()

obj2
calling grandchild::reset()
calling child::reset()
calling base::reset()

obj3
calling great_grandchild::reset()
calling grandchild::reset()
calling child::reset()
calling base::reset()

obj4
calling great_great_grandchild::reset()
calling great_grandchild::reset()
calling grandchild::reset()
calling child::reset()
calling base::reset()

obj5
calling great_grandchild::reset()
calling grandchild::reset()
calling child::reset()
calling base::reset()

obj6
calling grandchild::reset()
```

Notice in the case of `obj5` that it doesn't matter which hierarchical type -
not necessarily `base` - the chained `reset` is invoked on: if it recurses at all
it will recurse all the way to `base::reset()`.

And note in the case of `obj6` that invoking `reset` on an object of
a dynamic type `chain<P>`, rather than `chain<P,C>`, suppresses recursion: it is
equivalent to calling `P::reset()`.

The further problem of supporting multiple chained functions in each of the
hierarchy classes collapses into the problem of supporting one, since that
one can invoke whatever other member functions are desired. Likewise
the problem of passing arguments to chained functions collapses into the
problem of passing a tuple of arguments to one chained function.

(g++ 5.1/clang++ 3.6, C++14, trivially adaptable to C++11)

Comment: This solution indeed automates recursive calls completely, but it seems that for each hierarchy-callable method you have to add three implementations of it in `chain` classes. Moreover, if you want to have many hierarchies of such classes, you have to do even more work...